# A subset $R'$ of a ring $R$ which is a ring but does not contain $1 \in R$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Please give me an example of a subset $R'$ of a ring $R$ with the following properties:

- $R'$ is a ring.
- $R'$ does not contain $1 \in R$.

Comment: Is multiplicative identity part of the ring structure?

Comment: In the book I am reading now, a ring $R$ contains multiplicative identity.

Comment: and $R$ is commutative.

Comment: Just a remark: $R'$ is input as `R'` and not `R^{'}`.

Comment: Another place where the four element ring $F_2\times F_2$ works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ \Bbb Z \times \{0\} \subseteq \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z $$

Comment: Thank you very much for a very simple nice example. Kenny Lau.

Comment: More generally, whenever $e$ is an idempotent of a (not necessarily commutative) ring $R$, then $eRe=\{ere:r\in R\}$ satisfies the requested conditions.

Answer (score 4):

An obvious example is $R'=\{0\}$, but there are more interesting examples.

Suppose you found it; then call $e$ the identity of $R'$. By the property of the identity, $e^2=e$, so $e$ is an *idempotent* element of $R$.

Conversely, if $e\in R$ is idempotent, then $eR$ satisfies your requirements (if $R$ is commutative).

If $R$ is not commutative, choose $eRe$, sometimes called a *Peirce corner*, see https://math.berkeley.edu/~lam/html/corner1.pdf

Not all rings have nontrivial idempotents, that is, different from $0$ and $1$. If $e$ is idempotent, then also $1-e$ is. In the case $R$ is commutative, there is a ring isomorphism
$$
R\cong eR\times (1-e)R
$$
given by $r\mapsto(er,(1-e)r)$. Any product of rings gives rise to idempotents: if $R=S_1\times S_2$, then $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ are idempotents.

Comment: Thank you very much for perfect answer, egreg. But unfortunately it is too difficult for me.

Answer (score 0):

Another easy example: $2 \Bbb Z \subseteq \Bbb Z.$

Comment: Thank you very much, Alex Sanger.